# how to remove things in this pattern in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

```
123|abc|dog
4a6|adc|cat
...
```

I want to get rid of all characters up to the first '|' in each line in VIM.  The result would be:

```
abc|dog
adc|cat
...
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)?

Comment: This a *very* basic use of vim patterns: first of all, you should read the basics about it like `:help :s`, `:help pattern`... Anyway a quick command to do this could be: `:%s/.\{-}|//` (I just discovered that in this case, removing the two ending slashes is working as well: `:%s/.\{-}|`, but I don't know if it's a good practice)

Comment: What doe it mean by ".\{-}" part?

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made to solve this on your own](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and because [no research effort has been shown.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) Where did you look for solutions, what have you found, and why didn't it help you? Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
qqdf|jq10000@q
:%s/^.\{-}|//
:%norm df|
:%!cut -d '|' -f 2-
:%s/^[^|]*|
<c-v>G4lx
:%norm 4x
```

Comment: as you are listing as much solutions as possible, yet another one to add: `%norm df|`

Comment: Or: `:%s/^[^|]*|`

Comment: Use cut! `:%!cut -d '|' -f 2-`

Comment: Ah, yes, totally forgot `:%!`.